# Compare a String's Words With another String's Words

Tags: java, string-comparison

I have two strings containing letters and numbers separated by spaces. ex String1"elza7ma wa2fa fel matab" and String2"2ana ba7eb el za7ma 2awy 2awy".

I want to get each word of String1 is compare to all words of String2 and also generate percentage of compare words. If Percentage of compare words is greater then 80% return that words for further use.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: seems like an instruction cache

Comment: I have a string and find a name from that string by comparing the list of name which is saved in text file.

Comment: @Sham - that's not relevant.  The question you were asked was "what have you tried".  The point we are trying to make is that SO is not a "write my programs for me for free" service.  It is about answering your questions so that you can write your code yourself.  But in order for that to work .... YOU have to make an effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `split()` method of the `String` class to get each seperate word of the two strings returned to you in an array then you can loop through the arrays to find the matching words.
That's a pretty simple example and should get you started in the right direction. You will get better help if you try writing the code yourself first and then ask questions if something is not working correctly and provide some code for review.

```
String[] s1 = String1.split(" ");
String[] s2 = String2.split(" ");

for(String s : s1){
    for(String ss : s2){
        if(ss.equals(s)){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to do all of your work for you. try doing it and if it doesn't work post some code and I or someone else will be glad to help but I doubt anyone here is going to do all of your work for you.

Comment: Oky dear i try to get percentage.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) methods of the string class.
To seperate your string you only need to do:

```
String frag[] = String1.split(" ");
```

This splits the string into the fragments that are seperated by a space. You can now compare all of the fragments with each other by using a loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<frag.length(); ++i){
    if(frag[i].compareTo(frag2[i]) == 0){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear how to get percentage of each compare word??

Comment: @Sham Count how often the comparison is true (take a look at the compareTo article to see which one you need) and calculate the percentage based on that.